# Postgres text search with order by / sorting

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

My use case, is I need to to a text search on a field, and then order by another column, unrelated to the text search, but I can't seem to create an index that handles both.

Create table:

```
create table file (
id bigint,
path character varying(2048),
peers bigint,
text_search tsvector
);
```

Some indices to test:

```
create index idx_file_text_search_1 on file using gin (text_search);
create index idx_file_text_search_2 on file using gin (peers, text_search);
create index idx_file_peers on file using btree (peers desc);
```

Here is my main query:

```
explain analyze 
select * 
from file_fast 
where text_search @@ to_tsquery('whatever') 
order by peers desc 
limit 10;
```

Yet its only using the peers index:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.43..20870.27 rows=10 width=316) (actual time=2507.304..9016.220 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using idx_file_peers on file  (cost=0.43..18286146.09 rows=8762 width=316) (actual time=2507.301..9016.205 rows=10 loops=1)
         Filter: (text_search @@ to_tsquery('ole'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 497504
 Planning time: 0.399 ms
 Execution time: 9016.265 ms
(6 rows)
```

And when I try it without the order by, it appears to use text searching index:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=104.15..143.54 rows=10 width=316) (actual time=76.949..76.977 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on file  (cost=104.15..34612.36 rows=8762 width=316) (actual time=76.946..76.970 rows=10 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (text_search @@ to_tsquery('ole'::text))
         Heap Blocks: exact=10
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_file_text_search_1 (cost=0.00..101.96 rows=8762 width=0) (actual time=76.802..76.802 rows=515 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (text_search @@ to_tsquery('ole'::text))
 Planning time: 0.376 ms
 Execution time: 175.775 ms
(8 rows)
```

Does postgres really lack an index to be able to text search, and sort on another field?

Comment: did you try the manual on create index? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX

Comment: Yes, I used that exactly.

Answer (score 2):

dont know if you can improve the index but if second query is the faster one maybe you can split the query

```
with cte as (
    select * 
    from file_fast 
    where text_search @@ to_tsquery('whatever') 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
order by peers desc 
limit 10;
```

Comment: This is faster, but I'm so confused as to why. This one does use the correct text search index, then does a memory sort (not using my peer index), but its much faster! Why wouldn't postgres know to use the text search index first?

Comment: Is  like an assembly line. The cte is executed first so the only index need it is the `text_search` once you have a result data set (smaller than original) a memory table is created and the second query is executed using a memory sort

Comment: Thanks! This still seems like something postgres should be smart enough to do. As soon as I add the order by, postgres ignores my gin index.

Comment: Not expert on text search, but my guess is you cant have those order together because arent related. In standard composite index like `(id1, id2)` once you find id1 you just jump to a subtree with id2 already sorted so can be very efficient. But for text search you cant have anything related unless you create all words combination on the index